# Hide/remove empty carousel card

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have defined a form containing (1) a carousel:

```
items: [{
    xtype:'carousel',
    items:[{
        xtype:'fieldset'
        items:[{
            xtype:'textfield',
            name:'overview1',
            label: 'Overview 1'
        }]
    },{
        xtype:'fieldset',
        itemId:'details',
        items:[{
            xtype:'textfield',
            name:'detail1',
            label: 'Detail 1'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

and (2) a constructor

```
constructor:function(record) {
    ...
    if(record.get("showDetails")) this.down('fieldset[itemId=details]').show()
    else this.down('fieldset[itemId=details]').hide()
    ...
}
```

If I have *showDetails==false*, the fieldset is hidden to the point that the field is not visible. Yet, **the carousel does still have two cards**, but the second is empty. How do I remove the card from the carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could use the `remove`/`removeAt` function to get rid of the panel. However, this does needs quite some work when the tab may contain form data, and should be re-inserted at a later time, pre-filled with the form data that was in it before the tab was removed. ANd heck, I also wanted that form data submitted.

So I just used a function to hide that tab:

```
onActiveTabChange:function(carousel, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    var items = carousel.getItems(),
        newIndex = items.indexOf(newValue),
        details = carousel.down('field[name=DetailsTab]').getValue();
    if(!details && newIndex==2) carousel.setActiveItem(0);
    // WTF moment n° 4711: newIndex can be 1 or 2 because index 0 is the indicator; but setActiveItem takes 0 or 1...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, may be used simple panel container with card layout. For manipulating carousel items i suggest look to [carousel infinite source code](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/Infinite.html#Ext-carousel-Infinite), there is rebuildInnerIndexes method where item is removed from the list

```
rebuildInnerIndexes: function(activeIndex) {
    var indexToItem = this.innerIndexToItem,
        idToIndex = this.innerIdToIndex,
        items = this.innerItems.slice(),
        ln = items.length,
        bufferSize = this.getBufferSize(),
        maxIndex = this.getMaxItemIndex(),
        changedIndexes = [],
        i, oldIndex, index, id, item;


    if (activeIndex === undefined) {
        this.innerIndexToItem = indexToItem = {};
        this.innerIdToIndex = idToIndex = {};

        for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            id = item.getId();
            idToIndex[id] = i;
            indexToItem[i] = item;
            this.fireEvent('itemindexchange', this, item, i, -1);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = activeIndex - bufferSize; i <= activeIndex + bufferSize; i++) {
            if (i >= 0 && i <= maxIndex) {
                if (indexToItem.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    Ext.Array.remove(items, indexToItem[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                changedIndexes.push(i);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0,ln = changedIndexes.length; i < ln; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            id = item.getId();
            index = changedIndexes[i];
            oldIndex = idToIndex[id];

            delete indexToItem[oldIndex];

            idToIndex[id] = index;
            indexToItem[index] = item;
            this.fireEvent('itemindexchange', this, item, index, oldIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps